# Setting two different aliases [Name, 2016 + Name (2016)] with \defcitealias{}

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am trying to cite some government reports, in natbib style.

And the "Author" is the "Ministry of silly walks, jumping and related movement" or in short: MOSWJRM (which also is the official acronym).

So I would like to be able to cite them in the text like so:

"*According to MOSWJRM (2016), silly walks are defined as follows:*" or "*Walking with your shoes on backwards is very silly (MOSWJRM, 2016)*"

And have an entry in references like this:

"*MOSWJRM, Ministry of silly walks, jumping and related movement: The full guide to silly walking, 2016*"

My first idea was to simply set the author with some brackets as in `author = {MOSWJRM, {Ministry of silly walks, jumping and related movement}},`, but this gets ignored, resulting in an "*MOSWJRM, M.: The full guide…*" entry.

Seems like setting the whole author in double brackets, and using `\defcitealias{MOSWJRM:2016}{MOSWJRM, 2016}` is a way to do what I want, however, this only works for one way to cite. How do I make it aware of giving me different results when using `\citetalias{}` and `\citepalias{}`?

Comment: maybe if you would add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) your question gets easier to answer.

Comment: With biblatex it would be rather easy, you could use shortauthor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but is this the output you are seeking?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{MOSWJRM:2016,
        author = "{MOSWJRM, {Ministry of silly walks, jumping and related movement}}",
        year = {1986},
        title = {The \TeX book},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}


\defcitealias{MOSWJRM:2016}{MOSWJRM}

\newcommand{\mycitet}[1]{\citetalias{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}
\newcommand{\mycitep}[1]{\citepalias[\citeyear{#1}]{#1}}


\begin{document}

citep: \citep{MOSWJRM:2016}

citet: \citet{MOSWJRM:2016}

mycitet: \mycitet{MOSWJRM:2016}

mycitep: \mycitep{MOSWJRM:2016}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{\jobname} % if you’re using BibTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like way more than should be necessary, for what I would consider a quite standard situation, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @JC_CL I don't think so, as you are basically abusing the aliasing system. The design is made for situations like `\defcitealias{MOSWJRM:2016}{Paper I}` and not to replace something complicate, like including a year which format depends on the used style.