# Changing the appearance of an author name in the text but not the bibliography with \citet

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am citing a paper by Nelder and Mead (1963). However, I would like it to appear as "Nelder--Mead (1963)" instead of "Nelder and Mead (1963)". How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alias.

Put in the preamble:

```
\defcitealias{nelder1965simplex}{Nelder--Mead}
\newcommand{\mycitet}[1]{\citetalias{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}
```

and in the text:

```
\mycitet{nelder1965simplex}
```

Comment: Should that be `\defcitealias{nelder1965simplex}{Nelder--Mead (1965)}`?

Comment: Yes, however, I am now running into the issue that the parentheses are part of the hyperlink, when only the names and year should be...

Comment: problem is solved here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323868/setting-two-different-aliases-name-2016-name-2016-with-defcitealias